# yolov4 doesn't train on gpu

Tags: python, yolo

i'm trying to train yolov4 on google colab here's the code i used to change makefile

```
%cd darknet
!sed -i 's/OPENCV=0/OPENCV=1/' Makefile
!sed -i 's/GPU=0/GPU=1/' Makefile
!sed -i 's/CUDNN=0/CUDNN=1/' Makefile
!sed -i 's/CUDNN_HALF=0/CUDNN_HALF=1/' Makefile
!sed -i 's/LIBSO=0/LIBSO=1/' Makefile

!make
```

but when i train it still trains on cpu it displays this while training

```
 (next mAP calculation at 1000 iterations) 
 25: 1158.892578, 1137.819946 avg loss, 0.000000 rate, 3.695665 seconds, 1600 images, 214.912276 hours left
Loaded: 3.765689 seconds - performance bottleneck on CPU or Disk HDD/SSD
```

214 hours is literally too much time to train so my assumption that my model train using cpu not the gpu so how can i make train using the gpu?